# Using URL redirect instead of input param for WCF service

Tags: wcf, url-rewriting, dynamics-crm

While investigating the Organization.svc in Dynamics CRM, I found that it is using URL redirect for changing the Organizations. That means for each Organization it simulate URL to access Organization.svc.

There is just one SVC file but multiple URLs to access it e.g. Organization Org1 will have URL `http://CRMserver_name/Org1/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc` and Org2 will have `http://CRMserver_name/Org2/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc`

I was wondering if there is any benefits for doing this as compare to passing input param to SVC. Please share your thoughts on the pros and cons for these two things.

Comment: Thanks LazyOne for making question look better !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned something new today. Pardon me if you know this already.

There are two different things –

1. URL routing - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358760.aspx
2. URL rewrite - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx

URL routing is ultimate thing. It is totally virtual and no need to register routes in IIS. So now I know why Dynamics CRM is using it. Using routing client doesn’t need to specify Organization name for each method call of WCF service. While creating client object, URL itself gives that info. Client only needs to do this once and all methods are now aware of Organization name for particular WCF call.

This example can help get you started with URL routing for WCF - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662952.aspx

Hope this helps someone!
-Nilesh

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be cleaner URLs and also it follows a sort of conventions for Dynamics CRM. As far as I can tell, URLs have always been in the format `http://CRMserver_name/OrgName/...`

Comment: That makes sense. So as far as custom development in WCF is concerned, I guess then there nothing much other than clean URL we are getting with URL Redirect. But passing param is lot easier for developers correct?

Comment: Not necessarily, whether you receive parameters by GET or POST, you handle them the same way in the code behind. You should check out [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628610.aspx) to help you choose