# WCF endpoint configuration

Tags: asp.net, wcf, wcf-binding

I need to configure an endpoint in my WCF service. My service URL is something like.

```
http://mysite.com/Services/Service1.svc
```

I want to give clients the URL `http://mysite.com/MyService` to consume the service.

I'm tried below in my `web.config` but it's not working and when I navigate to `http://mysite.com/MyService` I'm getting the 404 error.

```
<service name="GateApplication.Services">
   <host>
      <baseAddresses>
         <add baseAddress="http://mysite.com/Services/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
   </host>
   <endpoint 
       address="http://mysite.com/MyService"
       binding="wsHttpBinding" 
       contract="GateApplication.IService1" >
   </endpoint>
</service>
```

Comment: How are you **hosting** your WCF service? Inside IIS? If so: then the IIS virtual directory and the path to the `.svc` file defines your service URL, and you cannot just change that via config

Comment: @marc_s hello! i'm just started with WCF.As far as i could understand end points are used to give a more user friendly URL for the consumers.Are there any other advantages other than that? and i'm using a shared hosting service which use IIS.please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Endpoints are the connection through which the outside world talks to a WCF service. But when hosting in IIS, the naming of the service URL is dictated by IIS - you cannot easily change it.

Comment: If you want full control over the service URL, you need to use **self-hosting** rather than using IIS. [See this MSDN documentation on how to do self-hosting of WCF services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx) for starters.

Comment: @marc_s so isn't it necessary to use end points always? nothing wrong with a WCF service without using end points right?

Comment: **NO**! A WCF service without endpoints is pointless..... you cannot communicate with it! The endpoints are **absolutely essential**!

Comment: @marc_s hello sorry to bother you. i know the end points are essential on client, for whom consume the service but is it necessary on the server also? i mean the Hosted WCF service.because currently i haven't specified end points on service but the client can communicate if he consumes service through http://mysite.com/Services/Service1.svc

Comment: Yes, they're essential on **both ends** of your communication! Otherwise, nothing will go. With WCF 4.0, you get *automagic* service endpoints on the server side - you still definitely have endpoints, you just don't have to explicitly define them

Answer (score 0):

Try the below configuration

```
<endpoint 
    address="http://mysite.com/Services/Service1.svc"
    binding="wsHttpBinding" 
    contract="GateApplication.IService1" />
```

go to solution explorer on right click and click on **Add service reference** and paste

```
http://mysite.com/Services/Service1.svc
```

and press ok

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are hosting on IIS.

In essense you can't just choose address in IIS in a way you can do it with self-hosting. However you can use either routing or dynamic path re-writing to have user redirected from the alias to your SVC

There are plenty of links about it. For example you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355165/how-to-remove-thie-svc-extension-in-restful-wcf-service) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776172/using-url-redirect-instead-of-input-param-for-wcf-service) as a reference.